# How to check what's happened to my flag?

Tags: support, flagging

I'm pretty sure I flagged my question [Why do they think WT1190F is low density?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214700/83380) a few days ago, suggesting/requesting that it be migrated to Space Exploration Stackexchange. When I originally asked the question 8 months ago, I wasn't very familiar with either site, but now I can see that there is probably a better chance of specific knowledge on this object there.

Is there any way I can double check that I did flag this question with this request, and if so find out if it is going to happen? I think a workaround would be to delete and copy/paste repost, but aren't situations like this what migration is for to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

You can check on your flagging history from your profile: on the Activity tab, at top right, there's a line with how many helpful flags you've raised.

> [image]

Click on that link and it will take you to your flagging history: which flags were marked helpful, and which ones were not and why they were not. If this was a declined custom moderator flag, then it will likely have a comment from the moderator that handled it explaining the situation.

---

In your specific case, migration is not possible because, generally speaking,

> only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated.

For more details, see [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) (which is generally the recommended first port of call for general questions about the SE platform).

That said, your question looks on-topic here, so I would recommend that you cross-post it to Space Exploration (or possibly [Astronomy Stack Exchange](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com)), and explicitly mark the cross-post on both versions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure there's a reason behind the 60 day limit, although it seems inconvenient in my case. It's good to know for future referece. I see zero helpful flags - does it mean I never successfully flagged, or possibly that my flag *was not* `successful=True`?

Comment: On the flags - it depends completely on what your flag history is, and that's between you and the moderators. Click on the link and you'll see all your previous flags.

Comment: On the 60 day limit, it's simply not great to be shovelling around old stuff in between sites, particularly since old (+migrateable) posts are likely to be abandoned by the OP, and maybe already seen by some fraction of the target site's users. If it's a good question, there's no harm in re-asking it.

Comment: (Oh, btw - the flag counts and histories on main and meta are independent. On main you should have two helpful flags as per David's image, on meta you don't have any.)

Comment: Thanks for that - blindingly obvious now :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile page, click on the "Activity" tab, and look toward the top right of the pane that appears. You'll see a link "[#] helpful flags". Click on that, and it shows you a listing of your flag activity.

[image: screenshot of activity page]

Regarding this particular case: your question wasn't migrated because only questions asked within the last 60 days are eligible for migration, and yours is older than that. Also, migration is only for questions that are off topic here. I think this question is on topic.

If you really want it to be on [Space Exploration](//space.stackexchange.com) instead, since the question doesn't have any upvoted (or accepted) answers, you can delete it here and repost it there.

Comment: Nice complete answer too - thank you very much for your time!